# how many streams can chrome show in WebRTC app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm trying to code an online class app with WebRTC, that teacher can watch all of students but students just can have teacher.
Teacher has to send out 30 streams of himself and has to receive 30 streams of student.

Teacher's Stream Specification:

Video: 720 * 640 pixels,
Frame rate: 15 fps,

//---
Student's Stream Specification:

Video: 64 * 64 pixels,
Frame rate: 1 fps,

(Although, if teacher wants to communicate with a student we can make quality better and turn it back to low quality at the end).

My question is, can teacher have all student's videos in chrome simultaneously?
I mean can a PC get all streams and show them to teacher. If Chrome has no problem with that, what config my PC does need?

Comment: the main issue is bandwidth ... pixels and frame rate mean nothing ... what is the "bits per second" of the streams?

Comment: I would not send The Teacher 30 streams. I would send a server the 30 stream and then _combine_ them into one to present to the teacher.

Comment: Dear Jaromanda X, I set the video to 256 Kbps and audio to 6 Kbps for teacher and student side.

Comment: Dear Nicolas, Yes you're right. It makes more sense but I didn't any example of this type. Do you see anything like you said for WebRTC?

Comment: not only bandwidth, but video decoding/encoding also takes a lot of cpu with many streams

Comment: Thank you. I think it's not possible to streaming 30 streams in a browser with a medium system configuration. Is it possible to use GPU for streaming?